# Can't connect to internet after starting DHCP

Tags: dhcp

I install isc-dhcp-server to connect with my Parallella board via ethernet cable, and I'm using internet via wifi.

However, after starting DHCP server, I can't connect to the internet. I checked the syslog and there seems to be conflict between eth0 and wlan0:

```
Dec 19 23:42:53 BoBeo dhcpd: Multiple interfaces match the same subnet: eth0 wlan0
Dec 19 23:42:53 BoBeo dhcpd: Multiple interfaces match the same shared network: eth0 wlan0
```

Here are my settings in the 'dhcp.conf'

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
option domain-name "bobeo.com";

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.200;
}
```

How can I resolve the conflict and connect to the internet while using the DHCP server. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use same IP subnet `192.168.1.0/24` for multiple network interface.

If you want to leave your WiFi (Router & `wlan0`) in `192.168.1.0/24` subnet, Change `eth0` static IP and DHCP server to a different subnet `192.168.2.0/24` for example.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't give you the full bounty. I was busy, and didn't have time to test  this solution.

Comment: That's ok, nice to know that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post here output of next commands

1. ip route
2. ifconfig
3. cat /etc/resolf.conf

Your desktop (which does not have internet ) role (dns or developers desktop) ?
Have you changed to use   manual configured DNS servers?
Did you make ping 8.8.8.8 
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.1 ?